# Dapper and mssql using stored procedure returning meaningful error

Tags: sql-server, dapper

I have a stored procedure inserts a row, and some conditions returns result set or single error code but when I use dapper return always same return class. so I couldn't understand If code gives me error or message rather than successful result set.

```
    public static List<Result> Results(int Id)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = BL.DataProvider.OpenConnection())
        {
            return connection.Query<Result>("SearchResultGet", new { Id = Id }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        }
    }

ALTER PROCEDURE SearchResultGet
@Id int
AS
IF(id != 0)
SELECT * FROM XX WHERE Id = Id
ELSE
SELECT -1
```

codes are just sample, doesn't have any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ORM/micro-ORM API that is going to like this; having a `select -1` for one set of cases is just ... not pleasant. Options:

- change the sproc to *not do that* - just run the regular `select` that returns zero rows
- add the logic to the `Results` method instead (or in addition to) the sproc - i.e. check whether `Id` is zero in the C#
- use a `return -1` rather than a `select -1` (although note that dapper doesn't make it trivial to capture return values)
- use a sql error (`raiserror`)